# Replace line in text file using python

Tags: python, replace, line

This is my program:

```
filetest = open ("testingfile.txt", "r+")  
ID = input ("Enter ID: ")
list = ['Hello', 'Testing', 'File', 543210]  
for line in filetest:
     line = line.rstrip ()
         if not ID in line:
             continue
         else:
             templine = '\t'.join(map(str, list))
             filetest.write (line.replace(line, templine)) 
filetest.close ()
```

I'm trying to replace an entire line containing the ID entered in filetest with templine (templine was a list joined into a string with tabs), and I think the problem with my code is specifically this part `filetest.write (line.replace(line, templine))`, because when I run the program, the line in the file containing ID doesn't get replaced, but rather `templine` is added to the end of the line.

For example, if the line in filetest found using the ID entered was `"Goodbye\tpython,"` now it becomes `"Goodbye\tpythonHello\tTesting\tFile\t543210"` which is not what I want. How do I ensure that line `"Goodbye\tpython"` is replaced by `templine` `"Hello\tTesting\tFile\t543210"`, not appended?

Comment: Did you mean: `filetest.write(templine)`?

Comment: i have tried doing that, but it still appends templine rather than replace line with templine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are reading from the file the file pointer moves as well and it can cause problems. What I would do is first read the file and prepare the "new file" that you want, and then write it into the file, as shown in the code below:

```
filetest = open ("testingfile.txt", "r")  
lines = filetest.readlines()
filetest.close()
ID = input ("Enter ID: ")
list = ['Hello', 'Testing', 'File', 543210]  
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
    if ID not in lines[i]:
        continue
    else:
        templine = '\t'.join(map(str, list))
        lines[i] = templine

with open("testingfile.txt", "w") as filetest:
    for line in lines:
        filetest.write(line + "\n")
```

I didn't change the logic of the code but be aware that if your file has, for example, a line with the number "56" and a line with the number "5", and you enter the ID "5", then the code will replace both of those lines.